# What does the .FXML.bak file do in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

When I create a JavaFx project in Netbeans, three files are generated:
    **.FXML** file,
    the **main Class**,
    the **controller**.

Later there's a fourth file that gets generated whose syntax seems to be completely the same as the orriginal **FXML** file, the **.FXML.bak** file. What does this file do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a copy of the original FXML file which is created as some kind of backup when you're saving changes in the FXML file.

.bak is a common extension for such backup copies.